# When do you call yourself a programmer

Tags: programming-languages

"A programmer, computer programmer or coder is someone who writes computer software" from Wikipedia

If you do frontend development using jQuery/CSS/HTML do you call yourself a programmer? If you develop PHP applications that deal with databases, do you call yourself a programmer?

Are you only a programmer if you write applications for desktops and mobiles? Is the web a place where the line between developer and programmer stops?

I imagine this question might be closed off or moved but if you look at the most viewed question on Stack Overflow its a question about Free C Learning material :)

Comment: belongs to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Straight from the FAQ: matters that are unique to the programming profession

Comment: Generally, if you are looking for a specific answer then SO is the right place. This question has no correct answer, and answers can only be subjective opinions. I'd second @Vladimir. This belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Straight from the FAQ: Avoid asking subjective or argumentative questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a significant amount of Javascript code, then I'd say you are a programmer.

(If you are just copying snippets of Javascript you've found elsewhere, then that doesn't count.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, then you use JavaScript, which is a programming language.